# Having issues with bool values and inputs for Unity, sprint system runs but doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script for unity 2022 useing c# and it is a 2d movement system that works on a top down perspective. I can move just fine, the problem is trying to add a sprint. It runs but dosnt move faster when I hold down shift or press it. The only error it says is that the bool isSprinting isnt being called even though it has multiple refrences so I'm kind of at a loss.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inputplswork : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    private bool isSprinting;
    private float moveSpeed;
    private float moveHorizontal;
    private float moveVerticle;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2D = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        moveSpeed = 2f;
        isSprinting = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
       moveVerticle = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
      // checks for shift key for sprinting
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
       { 
        isSprinting = true;
       }
       else 
       {
        isSprinting = false;
       }
       // if true then increased speed
       if (isSprinting = true )
       {
        moveSpeed = 3f;
       }
       else 
       {
        moveSpeed = 2f;
       }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(moveHorizontal > 0.1f || moveHorizontal < -0.1f)
        {
            rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(moveHorizontal * moveSpeed, 0f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        if(moveVerticle > 0.1f || moveVerticle < 0.1f)
        {
            rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, moveVerticle * moveSpeed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

The only idea I have for whats wrong is that I probably messed up with the syntax of the input for it; I dont know, if anyone can see where I went wrong. I did 'borrow' the code from a video which said it was okay to so it might not work with what is already there. Any help would be much appreciated. I also checked for any other questions but mine was too specific but if there is anything that does I would be happy to be redirected.

Comment: Because `    if (isSprinting = true )` sets isSprinting to true......

Answer (score 0):

try `isSprinting == true` instead of one =. You should also normalize your input so moving diagonally won't be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. You switch off `isSprinting` variable everytime right in the next frame after `Input.GetKeyDown` event was detected. So make next changes:

```cs
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
       isSprinting = true;
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
       isSprinting = true;
}
```

Long answer is... This kind of questions much faster to solve by your own. First of all you can consider the issue. If some code works, but you don't understand why, you can think of ways to see what actually this piece of code does. Unity provides us `Debug.Log` to see actual values. If you write something like this

```cs
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
      Debug.Log("Hold");
    else
      Debug.Log("Not hold");
}
```

And if you press the specified button in a play mode, you'll be able to see this kind of output:

(Don't forget to press "Collapse" button in console log panel)

[image]

Now it has to be obvious for you why it doesn't work.

P.S. By the way, Unity supplies new input system for a long time. I suggest you to consider to use it. You can read about it [here](https://medium.com/@antonswanevelder/new-input-system-with-unity-learn-lesson-1-ba45b6565d84) or you can google it by yourself. Although I understand that it's easier to start from tracking Input events inside `MonoBehaviour.Update` method, but this approach is messy. Event-base controls a much more elegant